# Where has this T-SQL code gone wrong. Not getting count as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
go
declare @sch_names varchar(50), @table_names varchar(50), @rwcounting int
set @sch_names='HumanResources'
set @table_names ='Employee'
set @rwcounting = 0
declare @fetchsql nvarchar(max)
set @fetchsql += 'select @rwcounting = count(1) as "countnum" from '+@sch_names+'.'+@table_names
exec(@fetchsql)
select @rwcounting
```

I am not getting the count from the table. Getting the count as zero. but expected count was 290.

Comment: Among other issues `declare @fetchsql nvarchar(max)` will mean that `@fetchsql` will be `null`. So `@fetchsql +=` will also be `NULL`. You should also use `QUOTENAME` here

Comment: In addition for your particular query you could simply `set @rwcounting = @@rowcount`; If all you are doing is finding how many rows a table contains see [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)

Comment: Debug your dynamic query. Do a `PRINT @fetchsql`

Comment: FYI, `sysname` is the correct data type for an object name, not `varchar(50)`, and whenever you inject an object name into a dynamic statement you **always** need to use `QUOTENAME`. What you have could be *very* dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had three mistakes

1.review this code because you can't concatenate null with string

```
set @fetchsql =
```

2.you must remove "as "countnum""

3.you must use  sp_executesql for return ouput

this is correct

```
go
declare @sch_names varchar(50), @table_names varchar(50), @rwcounting int=0
set @sch_names='HumanResources'
set @table_names ='Employee'
set @rwcounting = 0
declare @fetchsql nvarchar(max)=''
set @fetchsql += 'select @rwcounting = count(1)  from ' + quotename(@sch_names) + '.' + quotename(@table_names)

exec sp_executesql @fetchsql, N'@rwcounting int output', @rwcounting output

select @rwcounting
```

Comment: *"@fetchsql can't null"* Incorrect, it can be; ensuring you `NULL` the value of a variable containing dynamic SQL when unexpected thigns "happen" is a great wait to stop the execution of malicious code. Also declaring a variable with a value initially doesn't *stop* it being assigned `NULL` later.

Comment: yeah,I reviewed and  corrected #1